# Need clarity in copying a dask.dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

Can pandas.DataFrame.copy API can be exactly imitated in dask.DataFrame, using the following code?

```
from copy import copy
df2 = copy(df)
```

Is it simple copy or deep copy?
How can I do the other type of copy?

Or do I necessarily need to do the following?

```
df2 = dask.from_delayed(pandas.DataFrame.copy(df.to_delayed(),deep=True))
```

Will the 2nd code snippet completely solve my problem, or there are some caveats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2018-07-01, Dask dataframes don't support mutable operations, so copying shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. 

Necessity is related to the use-case, for example, I need to create a temporary version of a table to create lag time-series features from the previous version of that same table. The only way I can see for this is by creating a copy that is like a "temporary branch" of the data.